# Why are these xhost commands used here for running a docker container?

Tags: docker, wayland, sway, xhost

I am running a docker container. The suggested way to run it is

```
$ xhost +
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host

    
$ sudo docker run     -it     --rm     --ipc=host     -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY        -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:ro      [...]

    
$ xhost -
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
```

What do the two xhost commands do?

Why are they needed here with running a docker container?

What are their equivalents for SwayWM (Wayland)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first one turns off the X11 security model completely. The second one turns it back on. This is a very crude way to allow a program to interact with your gui session. (I would be very dubious about the quality of the build).

Comment: Thanks. what does it  allow for a program to interact with a gui session?